# Can't send email to myself via gmail and postfix forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spf, gmail

I set up postfix to forward email to my gmail account. I can send email from this server to my gmail, I can receive outside email and it's forwarded correctly (even from other gmail accounts). However, I can't send email from my gmail to this machine.

I get no error messages in postfix's log, it all looks fine. The email isn't marked as spam, it just never reaches my gmail inbox.

Here's postfix:

```
postfix/cleanup[4435]: B5BE7E0A06: message-id=<CABHVO+zD_LCYXWWiABRvXxb=rjez4uBXGo2N9__zkOWo1KVwOA@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/qmgr[4183]: B5BE7E0A06: from=<stefano.palazzo@gmail.com>, size=1416, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtpd[4431]: disconnect from mail-wm0-f46.google.com[74.125.82.46]
postfix/smtp[4436]: B5BE7E0A06: to=<stefano.palazzo@gmail.com>, orig_to=<hello@xn--y-5ga.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.06/0/0.03/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1449920800 r66si5494735wmd.91 - gsmtp)
postfix/qmgr[4183]: B5BE7E0A06: removed
```

Also [my postfix config](https://gist.github.com/sfstpala/52d17072e7b742401e45f53885ef2e59).

The SSL certificate is valid for the domain. The spf record of the domain looks like this:

```
TXT "v=spf1 ip4:212.47.242.239 ~all"
```

What's going on? What am I missing?

Comment: I experienced exactly the same behaviour lots of time ago and I ended with the assumption that GMAIL will **not** send you an e-mail **if** you're forwarding your mailbox to it. I've quickly searched on-line for some official info but have been able to get only this: https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/forwarding-to-gmail Again: I've been unable to find official references within GMAIL support web-pages. Sorry!

Comment: That seems to explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gmail is dropping the mails siltently. This seems to ba a policy by Gmail. Read this: [I’m having trouble sending messages in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2921561?hl=en&rd=1#CheckSent&ts=2921607%2C2922961%2C2923129%2C2923153%2C2923230)

> If a message you've sent never arrived at its destination, you should
>   first check your **Sent Mail**. Messages that you send to a mailing list,
>   or to an email address that's automatically forwarding your mail to
>   Gmail, will only appear in your **Sent Mail**.

Why is gmail doing this? This seems to be the answer: [Best practices for forwarding mail to Gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175365?hl=en)

> **Authentication**
>
> - Do not modify, remove or shuffle message headers or modify the body of the message. DKIM or DomainKeys signatures will break if the body
>     is altered, and all authentication information will be lost.
> - Common DKIM breakages include modifying the mime boundaries, anti-virus or anti-spam programs modifying the body of the message,
>     expanding the message recipient using LDAP, and re-encoding the
>     message.
> - Several highly-phished domains have asked Gmail to enforce strict authentication checks on their mail. These domains include **eBay**,
>     **Paypal, and Google**. If your mail server modifies the forwarded
>     messages from these domains, these messages will be marked as
>     phishing.
> - **One symptom of this problem is that a messages from these domains 
>     forwarded through your mail server to Gmail will have an
>     Authentication-Results header that show that DKIM did not pass, while
>     messages sent directly to Gmail will have a passing signature.**